# How do you trigger the biometric error of LAErrorBiometryNotEnrolled and LAErrorPasscodeNotSet?

Tags: ios, swift, biometrics

I am trying to present an alert controller in both cases where I am allowing the user to have the option of going into the settings of the phone and enable FaceID or enable the passcode but this is not happening.

I have tried to disable FaceID on the phone and then enabled FaceID but disabled it specifically for the app. For the passcode error, I have tried to disabled passcode in the settings but that alert controller is not coming up.

Not sure how to trigger these errors because nothing is happening.

Comment: Please share your tried code to trigger that alert controller?